# Unable to install ntfs-config

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I ran the command `sudo apt-get install ntfs-config`, but it displays the following line:

```
Unable to locate package ntfs-config
```

What should i do now to install this?

Comment: Visit [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481354/how-to-solve-unable-to-locate-package-error)

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 14.04 `ntfs-config` package is located in Universe repository. So you have to enable universe repository inorder to install `ntfs-config` package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```